# Script to generate html Beyond Compare folder differences

Tags: compare, directory, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I've found several ways to automate folder comparison using scripts in Beyond Compare, but none that produce the pretty html report created from Session>Folder Compare Report>View in browser.

[Here is an example of what that looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk4B3.png)

I would love to be able to find the script that gives me that html difference report.

Thanks!

[This is what I am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9nzD.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
load "C:\Users\UIDQ5763\Desktop\Enviornment.cpp" &
  "C:\Users\UIDQ5763\Desktop\GreetingsConsoleApp"
folder-report layout:side-by-side options:display-all &
  output-to:C:\Users\UIDQ5763\Report.html output-options:html-color
```

The documentation for Beyond Compare's scripting language is [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/scripting_reference.html#folder-report).  You were probably missing either `layout:side-by-side`, which gives the general display, or `output-options:html-color` which is required to get the correct HTML stylized output.  You may want to change `options:display-all` to `options:display-mismatches` if you only want to see the differences, and you might want to add an `expand all` command immediately before the `folder-report` line if you want to see the subfolders recursively.'

The `&` characters shown in the sample are line continuation characters.  Remove them if you don't need to wrap your lines.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately even with these changes it is still not giving the HTML stylized output. I added a screenshot of what I am currently getting to the bottom of my post.

Comment: The script appears to be correct to generate an HTML report, but your screen shot looks like plain text. Please make sure you're running the correct script and looking at the correct report file. If you're running an older version of Beyond Compare it might also help to update to version 3.3.13 or 4.1.6.